# image transform to webp image format

Tags: image-transforms

I would like to ask how to convert or transform image format to **webp**.

Based on Craft CMS Documentation 3.x, you can set the image format to **jpg**, **png**, **gif** and **webp** but there is no **webp** available in my CP.

https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/image-transforms.html#defining-transforms-from-the-control-panel

I would like to ask how can I convert it to **webp**, should I need install driver in my server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not seeing WebP as a format option, your server doesn't support webp. As per the [server requirements for Craft](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/requirements.html), you need either of the PHP extensions for images, GD or ImageMagick. Both of those can be compiled / installed with or without WebP (though a standard installation should include WebP by default by now).

If you're working locally or on a server you control, make sure to install/compile ImageMagick with WebP support. If you're using managed hosting, contact your server provider to do it for you.

Comment: Thank you. Though I am having a hard time installing ImageMagick on my local but it worked on GD2.

Answer (score -5):

our plugin will handle this among other things. Check it out here.
https://plugins.craftcms.com/one-plugin-fields

Effectively it'll transform the image, render it per target resolution and optimise. All while giving you the option for fallback images. So safari or edge wont break your site.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. WebP still needs to be available and configured on the server side.